# postgres intarray: ERROR: operator class "gin__int_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I've been running the same script without problems for quite a while and am now suddenly getting the "ERROR: operator class "gin__int_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"." error.
I'm not aware of having changed anything in my script and am making sure to create the extension intarray if it doesn't exist (and manually checked on the database that it's indeed there).
What could be going on here? I'd be grateful for any pointers.
Sample code and error are attached below.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test(
    temp_gid1           INTEGER[]
);

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS intarray;  
CREATE INDEX idx_gid1_with_intarray ON public.test USING GIN (temp_gid1 gin__int_ops);
```

> SQL Error [42704]: FEHLER: Operatorklasse »gin__int_ops« existiert
> nicht für Zugriffsmethode »gin«

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, but it does in the `intarray`  extension @swallner installs before creating the index.

Comment: Then it is probably a `search_path` problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : Thank you for the helpful hint, that was indeed the case! This time, I had already created the extension in another schema of the same database first (which I usually don't do), and that schema wasn't in the search path.